# Our dashboard reports are inaccurate - caching issue?

Tags: dashboard, cache, dashlet

We have a number of dashlets set up for various users to monitor what's going in in CiviCRM.  Sometimes data is missing though.  We run the report the dashlet is based on, and the data does show up there.  Afterwards, it shows up on the dashboard too.  Smells like a caching issue to me.

What is the best way to deal with this?  Is CiviCRM caching strictly controlled by the CMS (Drupal in our case)?  I have just set a maximum value for cache life; it was "none" before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one also throws me occasionally. You should reduce the **dashboard cache timeout** setting to '0' in /civicrm/admin/setting/misc?reset=1

Then it will load the reports dynamically each time you access the dashboard.

Comment: Thanks, I could have sworn I looked there, but I didn't see it.

Comment: Didn't even realize that was there. I'll look into how to edit book.civicrm.org and try to add the info to this page: http://gitbook.civicrm.org/the-user-interface/menu-dashboard-and-dashlets.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, dashlets are cached. However you shouldn't need to re-run individual reports to update the dashlets. Instead, use the link at the top-right of the dashboard page called "Refresh Dashboard Data".